# Cannot read properties of undefined for 3rd party library after useEffect has run

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, window

I am using an external 3rd Party that mounts onto the window object when the site loads. This library can be accessed using window.truste. My problem is that truste doesnt exist on the first render of my component and seem to load in a split second after.

```
useEffect(() => {
        const state = window.truste.eu.bindMap.state;
        if (validStates.includes(state)) {
            setValidState(true);
        }
}, []);
```

If i create a setTimeout function like so then I don't face any issues but this approach seems a little sloppy. I am wondering if there is a way to know that a library is loaded and then try to execute my code.

```
useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            const state = window.truste.eu.bindMap.state;
                if (validStates.includes(state)) {
                    setValidState(true);
                }
        },1000)
}, []);
```

Comment: What 3rd party JS, does it come with documentation?

Answer (score 0):

If the library lets you use it in a dependency array, do that:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (!validState && window.truste) {
    const state = window.truste.eu.bindMap.state;
    if (validStates.includes(state)) {
        setValidState(true);
    }
  }
}, [window.truste, validState]);
```

Otherwise if it's an asynchronous import, wait for it:

```
useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
    const otherLibrary = await import('other-library');
    const state = window.truste.eu.bindMap.state;
    if (validStates.includes(state)) {
        setValidState(true);
    }
  })();
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create a polling in `useEffect` check the `window.truste` is avaliable.

```
useEffect(() => {
  function check() {
    if (!window.truste) {
      setTimeout(check, timeout)
    } else {
      // use window.truste
    }
  }

  check()
}, [])
```